# Manual/Electrically controlled loaded spring release for door kick-down stopper

Tags: electrical-engineering, springs, servo, door

Hoping to upgrade [this or similar telescopic door kick-down stopper](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07ZWQQB7D) to release the stopper remotely. Wondering if there are standard solutions that would allow for electrical and manual loaded spring release on such telescopic kick-down door stopper using stepper motor or some other means (with kick release is preserved).

[image]

Comment: what criteria is acceptable

Comment: "standard solutions" appears to place a requirement for an off-the-shelf device, which I have not seen. I suspect the solution would be more DIY using some form of communications device combined with a power source and a solenoid. Maintaining the manual release option also complicates the overall picture, but is likely not insurmountable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An electric solenoid that drops the foot when powered and releases whem unpowered seems like the best solution.  This could be tied to fire systems to release doors for fire protection.  Note that you run the risk here of powering the solenoid when the door is shut, and you need a solution (manual circuit break) to allow egress in a fire.

Electro-magnets that hold open doors to stairwells is a similar application.

Comment: I guess [this stopper](https://www.amazon.com/Spring-Tiberham-Stopper-Stainless-Operated/dp/B07TX6C9MS/ref=sr_1_30?crid=1OU0GZEZJA1FC&keywords=Stainless+Steel+Easy+Step+Door+Stopper%2C+Spring+Loaded+Telescopic+Step+On%2FOff+Door+Stopper&qid=1648636618&sprefix=stainless+steel+easy+step+door+stopper%2C+spring+loaded+telescopic+step+on%2Foff+door+stopper%2Caps%2C143&sr=8-30) with [pull solenoid](https://opencircuit.shop/product/Push-pull-solenoid-12V) under the release lever would work great. Good point regarding emergency egress.